# mount composer vendor folder from composer container to another host server container

Tags: docker, composer-php, phpmailer, synology

as the title suggests I've created a composer container which starts fine. In the "volumes" section of my yml file I've mounted the :/app folder which should contain the vendor folder and composer.json file.  I've also mounted the same /app folder to the dev server container folder and both are empty...

I've been reading another stack question and can't get it to work [here][1]...

yml file below

```
version: '3'

services:
    composer:
        image: composer
        container_name: composer    
        command: install --no-suggest
        restart: 'no'

        environment:
        - PUID=1029
        - GUID=100
        - COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1    

        volumes:
        - /volume1/docker/devserver/external-includes:/app
```

The mount is shared by both the composer and dev server containers. This hopefully should from my limited knowledge mean all I have to do is restart the composer container to update composer.json and the vendor folder...
[1]: [Using phpmailer V6 with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672620/using-phpmailer-v6-with-docker-compose)

Comment: The `volumes:` section looks overly suspicious to me. Could you please elaborate in your question and present the rationale why you have choosen this specific value and explain the meaning of the comment message? When asking a question present the minimal example, not dead code and what not. You can write what else you have tried (and why) and that it didn't help, but having that many volumes within the docker-compose file IMHO requires an explanation at least.

Comment: And the existing Q&A material you referenced also uses a relative path to the volume. While its fine if you want to do something differently, you should explain why you have chosen it to do differently when you reference it, so that it is clear that you ask specifically about on how to do it your way. This will provoke better answers (and less comments).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is it related to Composer or PHPMailer?

Comment: Hi Hakre, I've updated my post. I forgot to remove the other mounts I had tried before posting.

Comment: Each of those lines that start with a dash need to be indented for proper yaml. Maybe they are indented in your actual file but I thought I'd point out the obvious, just in case.